# How to Make Hover Background Fade Smoothly In and Out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I have a list on my website and the `<li>` background is a 1 pixel black color image of 30% opacity which repeats to fill the whole `<li>`. It has a hover, which is a 1 pixel white color image of 2% opacity.

Instead of an instant appearance of the hover background, I want the hover background to smoothly fade in (and out).

HTML

```
<ul>
    </i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 1</li>
    </i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 2</li>
    </i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li{
    width: 572px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 14px 0px 14px;
    background: url('../images/black_op30.png');
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
}

li:hover{
    background: url('../images/white_op2.png') repeat;
}
```

I think what I want can be achieved with jQuery, but I have no clue how.

EDIT: Simple said, what I want is just to make the hover of the `<li>`s transition smoothly.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? I mean where does this fadein and fadeout fits in your scenario ?

Comment: fadein fadeout would not hightlight the li item .. instead it would hide it (display:none) .. which would be a problem as without it beeing there you cant make it reappear by using an event on itself...

Comment: @Ingo is right ,Lets us know What do you want to achieve ? The whole picture

Comment: i think what he wants is what i have posted in my answer a tad below, just have the background blending in and out as you hover over it... (jquery-ui using toggleClass)

Comment: Simply said, what I want is just to make the hover of the `<li>`s transition smoothly. I have never thought that such a small detail would be so much work.

Comment: @sedoc94 It seems to me that you have just started using jquery,I must tell you Jquery is javascript library and its has made things very easier same problem can be solved in javascript but with lot of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this most easily with css3 transitions like this:

```
li{
    width: 572px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 14px 0px 14px;
    background: url('../images/black_op30.png');
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
    -moz-transition: background 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    -o-transition: background 1s;
    -ms-transition: background 1s;
    transition: background 1s;
}

li:hover{
    background: url('../images/white_op2.png') repeat;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.02);
}
```

Note the transition is occurring between the to rgba versions of your transparent colors. You can achieve the same thing with jQuery, but its much more complicated and will not animate as smoothly. Also fading between transparent colors and rbga is not possible in IE, and with this technique IE will work fine and just wont fade (it falls back to your .png files where rgba is not supported).

IE supported method, (brace yourself):

```
 <li id="wrap">
     <div id="content">
          Content
     </div>
     <div id="fade-1"></div>
     <div id="fade-2"></div>
 </li>
```

CSS

```
#content, #fade-1, #fade-2{
    width: 572px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px 14px 0px 14px;       
    position: absolute;
}

#content{
    z-index: 3;
}

#wrap{
   position:relative;  
   width: 600px;
   height: 24px;
}

#fade-1{
   background: url('../images/black_op30.png');
   background:transparent url(../images/black_op30.png);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader»(src='../images/black_op30.png',sizingMethod='scale');
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);     
   border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;   
   z-index: 1;    
}
#fade-2{
   display:none;
   background: url('../images/white_op2.png') repeat;
   background:transparent url(../images/white_op2.png);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader»(src='../images/white_op2.png',sizingMethod='scale');
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.02);
   border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
   z-index: 2;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#wrap').hover(function(){
     $('#fade-1').stop().fadeOut();
     $('#fade-2').stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
     $('#fade-1').stop().fadeIn();
     $('#fade-2').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/7828.htm
http://api.jquery.com/hover/
http://api.jquery.com/stop/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

However this method will still yield worse results than the CSS3 method in all other browsers, so ideally you would use both and control the HTML, CSS and JS with an if statement to detect IE. Additionally IE9 does support rgba but not transitions, so for a best of all worlds scenario, you would have the IE version for ie6-8, a version using the jQuery color plugin:

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

for IE9 and the simple CSS3 for all other browsers.

OR you could say, 'hey cross fades are not that important to my design, its ok if those who have not updated their browser miss out.' Which is strongly what I would recommend.

Comment: Yes, but I want this also to work on older browser which don't support CSS3, so jQuery would be the option to go with (I think).

Comment: Only IE will not support this. In order to achieve the same effect in IE you will have to use two divs, one for each color and fade between them AND use IE's proprietary alpha image loader filter system. You are talking about quite a lot of extra work. I can show you if its really worth it to you.

Comment: I would not recommend using CSS3 although its awesome ,but we need to be backward compatible with multiple browsers...

Comment: Well if it's a lot of work, I'd still prefer jQuery which will work too in IE. And yeah dotNetSoldier.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier unfortunately that still wont work out. Not only do you have to have 2 elements to fade between, BUT a simple fadeIn fadeOut without the alpha image loader will result in the transparency being lost during the fade, it will appear as if its over a solid black background instead. This is due to IE's handling of .png files.

Comment: @dotNetSoldier additionally this problem only exists for IE, unless you care about FF 2.0.

Comment: @Sedoc94 also if you want to have anything in the div with the fading background, inorder to support IE with a fade you will have to have FOUR elements. A wrapper, two elements to be crossfading background, and a third for the content itself positioned over the crossfaders.

Comment: @Sedoc94 I added IE support to my answer, so far it the only answer that provides IE support to you specific situation. Hopefully is more clear the trouble you got yourself in ;) Also the IE filter system is very buggy, so you may encounter other glitches, like text dithering and just funky stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will give you an idea and a kick start,itz very easy

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(".yourCssClassNameHere").hover(funcOver, funcOut);
              function funcOver() {
                $("#Id of You want to fade in").fadeIn(100);//time is in ms
                }
               function funcOut() {
                $("#Id of You want to fade out").fadeOut(100);
                 }
           </script>
```

Another variant of this solution can be by using anonymous functions as @Joseph Torraca shows in his reply.

To make a specific `<li>` fadeout on hover,I have tested it,try this:

```
  <ul>
   <li onmouseover="$(this).fadeOut()">Hover me to disappear</li>
  </ul>
```

**For more info:**
http://api.jquery.com/hover/
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp
**FadeIn**
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
**fadeOut**
http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: I have not tried this out yet, but as far as I can predict is that this will make all my 20 items in the list react at once. I want only the hovered `<li>` to react to the hover.

Comment: You mean when user hovers over an specific <li> then it should fadeOut ?

Comment: Yes only the <li> where user hovers over should do that.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.yourclasshere').hover(function() {
        $('#idofelement').fadeIn(300); // Time in milliseconds
    , function() {
        $('#idofelement').fadeOut(300); // Time in milliseconds
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this mean that I have to make another element just for the hover background instead of declaring the hover background in the CSS?

Comment: @Sedoc94 Jquery will handle fadein and fadeout for you, you just need to apply those methods to the desired elements,go thru examples and links you will know it like a pro :)

Comment: No, it's not the easiest way. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you have to work on css2 and with different browsers, the imho best way is to use Jquery/JQueryUI

see http://jsfiddle.net/igambin/4CfC6/

you ll probably have to play around with it a bit... the idea to hover also has its value, maybe a combination will be exactly what you are looking for